# Curve sketching for $\ln(x^3 - x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

A few weeks ago I failed my math exam and today I revisited some problems.

We needed to analyse $\ln(x^3 - x)$ and I have problems finding the X and Y intercept.

The way I approached it was

Y intercept $= \ln(0^3 - 0)$ -> does not exist.

X intercept $ 0 = \ln(x^3 - x)$ which only can be zero if $\ln(1)$ so $x^3 - x = 1$ or $x^3 -x -1 = 0$

But in my exam I remember that I was not able to solve this problem. I just had a look at how wolframalpha solved the problem and the steps to solve it were quite complex and I am not sure if I even had the time to solve this problem.

Is there a clever way to get the X intercept?

Comment: You need to solve a cubic equation. Just google for that. Otherwise, as user146576 wrote, numerical methods. If you want me to elaborate around this last point, just post.

Comment: You need to use limits to analyse this properly.

Comment: The equation quickly becomes linear in $\ln(x)$ before that the equation is undefined as the argument is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no simple technique. The real root won't be "nice" anyway so the best method is to use a graphing calculator to approximate it.